# PowerShell Format-Table -wrap

Tags: powershell, active-directory, word-wrap

I have having problems trying to get PowerShell output to properly word wrap. Here is the command I am using:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like $firstAndLast} -properties memberof | Select-Object -Property @{label='memberOf';expression={$_.memberOf -replace 'CN=|,.*$'}} | Format-Table -wrap -property memberof | Out-String
```

and here are the results:

```
memberOf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
--------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{NetExtender Access, HR, AllCarrollton, ALLHR...}
```

I would like it to show all the results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1`

Comment: Even after calling that it still gives me same results. I also tried 20 just in case.

Answer (score 1):

if you print only "memberof" property you can do it:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "*j*"} -properties memberof | 
    Select @{label='memberOf';expression={$_.memberOf -replace 'CN=|,.*$'}} | 
        select -ExpandProperty memberOf -Unique
```

or try this for better view

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "*j*"} -properties memberof | 
    %{$name=$_.Name; $_.memberOf -replace 'CN=|,.*$' | %{ [pscustomobject]@{Name=$name;Memberof=$_}}}
```